# Application module instances in ampool not being reused

Tags: oracle-adf

I am following the ampool metrics for my adf application hosted on weblogic. I am running transactions using multiple user sessions. One of my application module's pool shows the max count of instances increasing abruptly compared to other application modules which are more rigorously being used. What could be causing my am instances to not be reused but always create new ones? Any direction would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the AM pooling setting for the AM? Did you change the settings or keep the defaults?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are accessing this AM from code that doesn't release the AM back to the pool?